# Rounding fixed point integers

Tags: math, interest-rate, fixed-point

If I'm using fixed-point arithmetic to represent rates, for example, 2% in ray (27 decimal precision) would be `102000000000000000000000000000`.

If I had a rate like `101333333333333333333333333333` (1.33%), how can I round it to the nearest 0.25%?

I would want `10125000000000000000000000000` (1.25%) to be the result.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you always need to round to the nearest .25% interval (.00, .25, .50. 75)? Always round up or down?

Comment: Yes, the nearest .25% interval. So for example with 1.3% it’d go to 1.25%, 1.4% to 1.5%. Although I’d accept a solution that rounds down too e.g. 1.3% and 1.4% both rounding to 1.25%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are integers so you can round them like they were integers.

To round integer A to B proceed as following trunc(A / B) * B.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.9.0;


contract Test  {

    uint256 public one = 10**27;
    uint256 public two_percent = 10**27 + 0.02 * 10**27;
    uint256 public rate = 10**27 + 0.01 * 10**27 + uint256(0.01 * 10**27) / 3;
    
    uint256 public round = 0.0025 * 10**27;
    
    function roundDown() public view returns (uint256) {
        return ((rate / round) * round);
    }

    function roundUp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return (((rate + round - 1) / round) * round);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was doing some testing with `1014999999999999999992500000` and the result was `1012500000000000000000000000`. I would have expected the result to be `101500000000000000000000000`. How can this be remedied?

Comment: @rosendin The trick is to add `round - 1` before dividing by `round`. So the formula will be `(rate + round - 1) / round` then multiplying by `round` should give you the scale desired. So `(((rate + round - 1) / round) * round)` is the final formula.